# What will be purpose string of NSUserTrackingUsageDescription for Firebase/Crashlytics & Firebase/Analytics?

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, app-transport-security

As Apple requires developers to receive the user’s permission through the App Tracking Transparency framework to track them or access their device’s advertising identifier (IDFA) With iOS 14.5

I am using **'Firebase/Crashlytics'** & **'Firebase/Analytics'** in my app for crash reports. So I added below purpose string into my info.plist

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key> 
<string>This identifier will be used to collect Crash Data.</string>
```

But still they rejected app with below reason.

```
Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage


We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the AppTrackingTransparency framework, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the AppTrackingTransparency framework in the purpose string.

To help users make informed decisions about how their data is used, all permission request alerts need to specify how your app will use the requested information.

Next Steps

Please revise the relevant purpose string in your app’s Info.plist file to specify why your app needs access to the user's AppTrackingTransparency framework. Make sure the purpose string includes an example of how the user's data will be used.

You can modify your app's Info.plist file using the property list editor in Xcode.
```

Can someone please suggest to me, which string I need to add as a purpose string for this one? So it can sufficiently explain the usage.

Also, I found Add In-App Messaging to your app from google document.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14

But have some doubts about this one so someone please let me know is it the correct solution and I need to implement it or it can be possible by just updating the purpose string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it more detailed. You can say something like `This identifier will be used to collect Crash Data and in-app activity in order to improve functionalities and user engagement`. Or something alike.

In your `String` you only make reference to `Crashlytics` but you're missing reference to`Analytics`.

It is possible that Apple answers back saying something like they didn't find the Alert in your app after doing the correction of the String. If that happens, you just have to answer them that the alert only shows once per device (if so), and the class where you display the alert (commonly used in the `AppDelegate`).

Comment: Thank you for the information. Let me try with this. Just let me know your thoughts on In-App Messaging if you have any idea.

Comment: Regarding that, Apple will not take that into account for publishing your app on the Appstore (as it is an issue related with Firebase API). However, I think that you should add the message, because Firebase docs say that. But, I think that you may ask another question focused just on that topic. Is it really necessary to implement both messages of Tracking Transparency? I don't know. Maybe someone knows more detail on that.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your efforts and information mate.

Comment: Your welcome. And a final remark. Apple service for publishing in their store is pretty good. They usually answer in some hours. So, if they don't approve your app again, you should ask them directly (there's a message ui in App Store Connect).

Comment: Thank you. App got approved with the above-mentioned purpose string. I Will try In-App Messaging in my future apps and will post here if that will be one of the solution too.

Comment: What is we are collecting user's email id also for the analytics purpose?
Will this string be acceptable for Apple?

Comment: @Vin Yeah it should work. However, adding extra information to the identifier gives more accurate information to the user. Take into account that, if you are planning to sell Analytics, the user and Apple should know, or you may get in trouble when they find out.